# How to keep git repo on vsts in sync with mercurial repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, mercurial

I recently migrate the mercurial repo to git using hg-fast-export
and created a mono-repo on git VSTS. And now I want repositories inside mono-repo should be in sync with mercurial repositories.How to do that ?
Also it will be great if there is any script available for this.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have converted the mercurial repo to git repo using the hg-fast-export tool, so you want to keep the **local git repo** and the remote azure devops repo in sync, right? If so ,I think you can share code with push.

```
git push <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pushing?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line) for details.

Comment: Actually I want azure devops repo in sync with mercurial repo.We haven't migrated fully yet, so developers are still pushing changes to mercurial, and those changes should present on devops repo.

Comment: I'm new to Azure devops so I might be wrong. But I'm thinking like we can have build pipeline with task group that will update git repo with mercurial changes. And let's say we perform this activity once in a day or two. Is that possible ?

Comment: I think push should be infeasible between different version controls.Azure devops repo currently only supports git and tfvc, so if you want to push changes to git repo, I think you need to convert mercurial to git first.